# VB.NET - Click Login Button on Webbrowser page

Tags: vb.net, button, authentication, webbrowser-control, getelementbyid

I'm trying to click a submit button on a website, I'm doing it via element by id:

```
webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("Enter").invokemember("submit")
```

Website button:

```
<input value"Enter" type="submit" />
```

But its not working

Would appreciate some help,

Thanks

Comment: What's your error of exception?

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT* :

```
For Each htmls As HtmlElement In WebBrowwer1.Document.All
    If htmls.GetAttribute("value").ToLower = "enter" Then
       htmls.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The website is not mine so i cant change it ,